# Prevent program from being debugged

Tags: c#, security, reverse-engineering

I was reading on the internet about how it is always possible to decompile mostly everything. will adding this method make it harder for a hacker to decompile a program:

```
void PreventProgramFromBeingDebuged()
{
     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{

         while(true){
             var a = DateTime.Now;
             Thread.Sleep(10);
             var b = DateTime.Now;

             // if difference in time is greater than 1 second it means the program has stopped executing

             if( (b-a).TotalSeconds > 1)
               // then make appliction crash or make it behave the way it is not suppose to
         }      
     });
}
```

That method is kind of obvious but you can have two threads being synchronized by a semaphore making the same code harder to understand. Having a method like that will make the life harder for a hacker? Or does a hacker does not have to debug a program in order to decompile it?

Comment: I don't think the word "debugged" means what you think it means.

Comment: What you are looking for is a (byte)code obfuscator, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompiling can be done without running the code.  In fact, can decompile, take this code out, recompile.

Comment: +1 thanks! What happens if I make several other parts of my code depend on that code. For example I use reflection to see if that method exist and I place that validity 1000 times. The hacker will have to find all those 1000 intances where I check for that right? So if the hacker removes that code then he will have to find all the places where I check for that making it harder for him.

Comment: I'd then just change the If condition so it never does the bizzare behaviour

Comment: The point of adding that function is so someone can't view your code, correct? As Keith pointed out, since your code doesn't have to be running for someone to decompile it, then clearly adding that function 1000 times isn't going to make a difference. What you need to Google is how to obfuscate your code. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082%28v=vs.107%29.aspx

Comment: whatever you do, some one will be able to hack it if determined,  point is to make it just painful enough through things like obfusication, and don't invest much time in it.  Because as soon as its cracked all that time invested in stopping cracking is wasted. The only kind of successful prevention is hardware based protection, like on playstation.  Much much harder, but even then, not 100%

Answer (score 3):

What your code actually does is cause your program to crash if the users system comes under heavy load (running low on memory or other resources). Instead of preventing debugging, you are introducing a nasty [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Often when you attempt to block someone from reverse engineering your code, you are setting yourself up for problems down the road from actual customers.

**Edit**: Your program is also likely to crash whenever the users computer automatically syncs its clock with a time source.

Comment: +1 for letting me learn the terms Heisenbug, Bohrbug, Mandelbug and Schroedingbug ;^)